# disassociate EIP and then convert to vps eip

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, elastic-ip

I have an eip that I want to convert from scope EC2-classic to VPC. Can I disassociate, convert to VPC eip, and then just re-associate with the same ec2 instance? I'm not sure if I will be able to reattach it to an instance, not in the VPC.

Answer (score 0):

Once you convert it to VPC, you cannot attach it to an instance that is not in a VPC. You can't attach a VPC EIP to an EC2-Classic instance, and you can't attach an EC2-Classic EIP to a VPC EC2 instance. This is the entire point of the conversion action.